# Is there workarounds with no declare-sort supported in some Z3 binding?

Tags: racket, z3

I am not quite familiar with Z3, but have to use it to do some project.

I am using the [Z3 racket binding](https://github.com/sid0/z3.rkt), it has the textual interface like SMT-LIB v2, able to eliminate universal quantifiers, but it does not yet support `declare-sort`, while my model needs some kind of customized type definition ( I can't think of how to only use `Int` in my model yet..)

In this case, if I want to use the binding, how can I work around to get the feature of `declare-sort`
in my model? Is there something similar in Z3?

or what's the usual tips to work on some type that not supported in Z3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your best bet to get an answer is to mail Siddharth Agarwal directly.

Comment: Asked. and he suggested to use `declare-datatypes`.